# $applyを使っても$scopeに反映されない

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui, angularjs

Onsenを使用してアプリを作っています。
以下の順番でリストを作ろうとしています。

１．外部にデータを作成
２．アプリ起動時にindexedDBでテーブルを作成し、外部データを格納
３．ページ読み込み時、indexedDBからデータを変数に格納し、$scopeへ引き渡す
４．ng-repeatにてリストを作成

３の別関数を呼び出しているため、$applyを使っているのですが、リストが反映されません。

この関数はちゃんと動きます。
（３秒後にリストが表示されます）

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.items = [~~];
    });
}, 3000);
```

getDataを使い、外部からデータを持ってくる過程を挟むと、動かなくなります。
ただし、ログは正常に変数の情報が出てきます。

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        getData()
            .then(function(value) {
                $scope.items = value;
                console.log(value);
            });
    });
}, 3000);
```

途中で関数を呼び出していることが原因なんでしょうが、どうして駄目なんでしょうか？
又、ほかの何かいい方法はないのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3):

thenに渡している関数は非同期で呼ばれるので、そのタイミングで$scope.$applyしても無駄です。
$scope.$applyはthen内で呼ぶ必要があります。

```
setTimeout(function () {
    getData().then(function(value) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.items = value;
            console.log(value);
        });
    });
}, 3000);
```

Comment: なるほど、場所が悪かったんですね。

Comment: 指摘された通り修正したら無事動きました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @CoolPon 解決したようでしたら解決した回答の承認を行ってください。